# Merge and fill R from two dataframes on date

Tags: r

I have reproduced my example as follows:

```
x<-as.Date(c(as.Date('2015-01-01'):as.Date('2016-01-01')), origin='1970-01-01')
dates<-as.Date(c(as.Date('2015-01-01'),as.Date('2015-03-04'),as.Date('2015-07-01')),origin='1970-01-01')
values<-c(3,7,10)
```

What I would like is an output dataframe where `values` for a particular date in `x` are joined to the most recent, but historic, date entry. For example:

```
x, value
2015-01-01, 3
2015-01-02, 3
....
2015-03-04, 7
2015-03-05, 7
....
2015-07-01, 10
2015-07-02, 10
....
2016-01-01, 10
```

I've currently implemented this through a `for` loop, but it feels slow and horrendously inefficient - I'm sure there must be some way in R to do it more automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like it

```
x<-data.frame(x=as.Date(c(as.Date('2015-01-01'):as.Date('2016-01-01')), origin='1970-01-01'))
dates<-as.Date(c(as.Date('2015-01-01'),as.Date('2015-03-04'),as.Date('2015-07-01')),origin='1970-01-01')
values<-c(3,7,10)

a=data.frame(dates,values)
y=merge(x,a,by.x='x',by.y='dates',all.x=T)
colnames(y)=c("x","value")
test=function(i){

  if(is.na(y[i,2])){
    if(i==1) return(NA)
    return(test(i-1))
  }else{
    return(y[i,2])
  }
}

y$value=sapply(1:nrow(y),test)
```

Comment: Seems to do the job! Will apply to my real world problem and see :)
Edit: I've just realised I've oversimplified my problem. Your solution is correct for the problem posed, but I've way oversimplified my problem. Will see if there's any way I can make it more representative.